# Velocities of points along an inextensible string

Tags: classical-mechanics

It is a well known constraint that velocities of points along an inextensible taut string or rod is constant. This is, for instance of use in the following problem:

[image]

If a rod slides along the wall and ground such that the velocity of the point on the  ground toward the wall is $v$ at an instant (call this point $A$), we can find the velocity of the point on the wall (point $B$) by taking components along and perpendicular to the rod and equating the components along it.

This principle seems to be physically reasonable as well. However, I came up with a seemingly paradoxical situation.

Consider a pulley around which a string is wrapped and is being unwound with a velocity $v$

[image]

Clearly, for all points on the thread along the pulley, they will have a velocity $v$ tangential to the pulley, consistent with our principle. But suppose we go into a frame translating with a velocity $v'$ with respect to the center of the pulley.

In this situation, points along the thread no longer have the same velocities along it. How come?

Comment: "velocities of points along an inextensible string or rod is constant" is false.  For example, in the pulley, every point has a different velocity.  The constraint for being a rigid body is more complex than simply a uniform velocity.

Comment: If I hold the two ends of a piece so string so the centre of the string hangs slackly, then I can give the two ends any relative velocity I want.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention explicitly that the string should be taut as well. I will do so.

Comment: Just being taut is not enough. The string would have to behave as if it was rigid, but in your example you are bending the string as you unroll it.

Comment: @Paul: I believe I worded it a bit inaccurately. I should have said, components of velocities of points on the string along the string is the same for all points. I will add that in too.

Comment: @Gerard, that's not correct either.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Okay, I think you're right. But I'm still confused. How exactly are constraints then defined for strings and other rigid bodies? Because that is the approach I was exposed to in some of the problems in my class.

Comment: @Paul: Then what is the correct definition? I know there is some problem in my definition, that is why a contradiction arises. Hence the question

Comment: @Gerard, I moved response to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a rigid body, the velocity can be decomposed into translational and rotational components. The translational velocity is the same at every point, while the rotational velocity is different, as it depends both on an angle and the distance from the axis of rotation.  The contradiction can be resolved by looking at both of these, not just translational.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit with reference to the pulley example I gave? Where am I missing out on the 'rotational' component of velocity?

Comment: In the initial case, the pulley has a translational speed equal to zero, with rotational velocities easy to determine.  In the new frame, the translational velocity will not be $-v'$, while the rotational velocity will be the same as before.  The total velocity will vary according to the different directions, but this does not change the overall result.

Comment: That should be "translational velocity will be $−v′$."

Comment: @Gerard, does that answer your question?